# Is CBFC certificate required for Hollywood movies before release in India?

Tags: content-rating

In India, any kollywood or bollywood movies get certified by Central Board of Film Certification before hitting to theaters.

Is it same for the Hollywood movies? Do they get certified also? Are hollywood movies in original and dubbed to be certified by Central Board of Film Certification before it releasing in Indian theaters?

Or For Hollywood movies , there is any certification board for recognizing it?

Comment: I have seen many Hollywood movies showing CBFC certificate before movie. That means hollywood movie too required CBFC certificate before telecasting in India because of censer and other issues. But i don't have any official wording link.

Comment: For dubbed movies i have seen , but i am not sure. But direct release of hollywood movies is doubtful for me...

Comment: Fix the title of the question, i think its unclear...`Is CBFC Certification Required For Hollywood Movies before releasing in india?` may be the right title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of Hollywood movies to be broadcast in India, certification is a must.  There are a few examples:

1. Under the **A** category the board usually allows the portrayal of very strong, gory, graphic, brutal and/or sadistic violence. Film such as Prometheus (R-rated in the US) have received this certificate.
2. Under the **U** category, only mild sexual references and sensuality is permitted. Moderate sexual references and undetailed sexuality is allowed under the UA category. Strong sexual references and detailed sexuality is restricted to **A** category only. Examples include Friends with Benefits and No Strings Attached, both R-rated in the United States. But in 2011, The CBFC banned the film The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo on account of heavy nudity and sexuality. Cut version is available.
3. The board is quiet strict towards censorship of profanity. Only mild language and mild swear words are allowed under the **U** category. Moderate profanity and swear words are permitted under the **UA** category. Films under the **A** category do not have any limitation on the bad language that is used. The strongest terms such (eg. fuck and cunt) are allowed only under the **A** category. Films such as The Hangover and The Hangover Part 2 (R-rated) have received this certificate.

This is the process how Hollywood films get rated by CBFC.

Comment: "Films can be publicly exhibited in India only after they have been certified by the Central Board of Film Certification." [cbfcindia.gov.in](http://cbfcindia.gov.in/)

Answer (score 2):

Anything to be played in theaters in India, needs CBFC certification (or rating). Let it be a movie (in any language, of any origin) or an advertisement, it needs the certificate. Playing videos directly in theaters, without certification is an offense in India. For CDs and DVDs certification is advised, but it is not needed for non-Indian movies.